# How to use different themes between main class and child classes in swing java

Tags: java, swing

I made a desktop application where it has may classes, and each is set to its own design and theme, but when I switch to the child class from main class, the theme of main class affects and removes the theme of secondary classes.
Please help me to let custom JFrame class be independent on its theme (LookAndFeel).

Main class theme is set as follow :

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) 
          {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.aero.AeroLookAndFeel");
           }
       }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Main().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Child class is set as follow:

```
     public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {


        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VisitStudents.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VisitStudents.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VisitStudents.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VisitStudents.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new VisitStudents().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: A look and feel is intended to be global

Comment: @Lokesh,  Means that there is no way I can change it to such Jframe class ?

Comment: Not really, no ...

Comment: *"..and each is set to its own design and theme"* What is the point of them having different themes?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I would like to meant th `LookAndFeel`

Comment: I always thought you were referring to the look and feel. The question remains. ***Why?***

Comment: Do you need this for some sort of LaF selection or LaF demo (displaying and comparing components in different LaF)? It is possible to dynamically change LaF during runtime but all the components displayed will have the same LaF.